# Implementing a trigger to mask column data

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am working on a requirement.
I have to apply trigger to mask data to a particular column in the database.
The table has 4 columns, firstName, lastName, userID, password. I want to write a trigger that masks the passsword column.

Here is the trigger, but its not working as expected.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dmm_live.TRG_I_TUSER_PASSWORD_HASHING
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON dmm_live.SampleHashPassword
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
/*  Package     :
 *  Author      :
 *  Created     :
 *  Description : Trigger
 *
 */
 vType VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
 IF INSERTING THEN
  vTYPE  := 'I';
 ELSIF UPDATING THEN
  vType := 'U';
 END IF;
 IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
     INSERT INTO dmm_live.SampleHashPassword (password) values utl_i18n.STRING_TO_RAW(password, 'AL32UTF8');
    --SET PASSWORD =utl_i18n.STRING_TO_RAW(PASSWORD, 'AL32UTF8');
 END IF;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  NULL;
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

In a trigger you can set or change the values of a column in the updated table - that is done by referencing the column as a bind variable. Basically this is invoked during the dml process, so you wouldn't do a insert into the table (remember you're *in* the actual insert process).

I removed the unused lines of code.

One remark... `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` is very scary. That means you don't care if anything goes wrong. I would want to see the error, log it and probably display an error in the application as well...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dmm_live.TRG_I_TUSER_PASSWORD_HASHING
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SampleHashPassword
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
/*  Package     :
 *  Author      :
 *  Created     :
 *  Description : Trigger
 *
 */
 vType VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
 :NEW.SampleHashPassword := utl_i18n.STRING_TO_RAW(password, 'AL32UTF8');
    --SET PASSWORD =utl_i18n.STRING_TO_RAW(PASSWORD, 'AL32UTF8');
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  NULL;
END dmm_live.TRG_I_TUSER_PASSWORD_HASHING;
```